# R function that will output number of response options for a variable?

Tags: r

If in my survey data (loaded from a csv file) I have a variable with 5 response options, but Ps only responded 1:4, is there any R function that will output "5" if I apply that function to the variable?

Comment: please provide some data

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-specify that column as a factor with the appropriate levels that the variable *could* take.

```
#Assuming that the values in myDF$myVar have the values 1:4, but COULD have been 1:5.
myDF$myVar <- factor(
    x=myDF$myVar, 
    levels=1:5, 
    labels=c('What a 1 means', 'What a 2 means', 
             'What a 3 means', 'What a 4 means', 
             'What a 5 means')
)
```